# git merge appears successful but HEAD and origin tags are left in the file

Tags: git, merge, winmerge

I have configured my git instance to use winmerge as the comparison tool using the following options:

```
git config --global merge.tool winmerge
git config --replace --global mergetool.winmerge.cmd "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe\" -e -u -dl \"Base\" -dr \"Mine\" \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""
git config --global mergetool.prompt false
```

When I run "git mergetool" on a conflicted file I see the winmerge window with the conflicting files and I am able to use winmerge to resolve the conflict as per normal merging.

When I save the file and am prompted by git to answer if the merge was successful I answer "y" and I think I am done.

However when I look at the newly merged file I see the <<<<<<< HEAD and >>>>>>> origin/master marks (these were not in the winmerge window when I saved the final merged file). I also see LOCAL.bak and REMOTE.bak versions of the file in the folder.

I've never had the HEAD and origin markers left in the merged file before nor have I had the LOCAL.bak and REMOTE.bak files left after a merge. It's as if they were added after I answered "y" to the successful merge question since they were not displayed in the winmerge window. Am I missing a configuration option of some sort? I can't seem to find out why it's doing what it's doing.

Comment: Is it possible that winmerge returns a non-zero exit code that makes git think the merge failed? But then, why does it ask you...

Comment: @Tassilo Horn from my point of view everything appears to be successful and the merged file looks as I need it to look when I save in winmerge but after it closes, the file has the HEAD and origin tags in it so they're apparently added after winmerge closes or through some other process of which I am unaware.

Comment: Just test by invoking winmerge from the command line on some test file, save and exit as you did before, and check its exit code using `echo %errorlevel%`. (I hope that's the correct variable on windows.)

Comment: @Tassilo Horn just checked echo %errorlevel% returns 0 after I exit winmerge

Comment: Ok, then it's something else. And I guess the changes you did persisted until after the exit, too, right?

Comment: @Tasso Horn they looked fine in the file when I saved and closed winmerge.

Comment: Does this config work for you? https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524

Comment: @Tassilo Horn That worked !!!!! Please post this as an actual answer instead of a comment so you get the credit you deserve !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up the git mergetool wrongly.  A working config (posted at https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524) for using winmerge as difftool and mergetool is:

```
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
    keepTemporaries = false

[merge]
    tool = winmerge

[mergetool "winmerge"]
    name = WinMerge
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = "/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e -dl \"Local\" -dr \"Remote\" $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED

[diff]
    tool = winmerge

[difftool "winmerge"]
    name = WinMerge
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = "/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

Answer (score 0):

The .bak files are created by WinMerge when saving a modified file. If you look in the WinMerge options, you'll see that the default is to store these backup files (which are 'pre change safety copies', if you like) in the same folder as the original files. You can opt to have them stored in a different folder instead.